# Frank Shearar SIP Component

Tags: delphi, sip

I am looking at the demo program by Frank Shearar and cannot build the demo program. I fixed up all the references to "missing files" and the last errors that I am trying to fix are related to differences in the interface in classes and how they are used now...

```
Self.CalleeMedia := TIdSDPMultimediaSession.Create(Self.Profile);
```

vs

```
Self.CalleeMedia := TIdSDPMultimediaSession.Create(Self.Profile, ???, ???);
```

I know the interface now looks like....

```
constructor TIdSDPMultimediaSession.Create(Profile: TIdRTPProfile; 
  Factory: TIdSdpMediaStreamFactory; ExecutionContext: TIdTimerQueue);
```

and I could just add...

```
x := TIdSdpMediaStreamFactory.Create;
y := TIdTimerQueue.Create;
```

and pass these in? Or pas nil in both cases. There are a few other places where I get similar errors when building the demo program. Do I just need to create other objects that are required? If not, what additional steps are needed? Any assistance to get me started would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? The demo should work straight away for any of Delphi 6, 7 and BDS 2006. In particular, I wrote the stack using Indy 9, which is really old. At any rate, extra details on your errors/problems much appreciated!

Comment: for future reference: https://github.com/frankshearar/SipStack

Answer (score 1):

I suspect I simply forgot to update the demo in line with the SDP API's interface!

Create the `TIdSdpMediaStreamFactory` and `TIdTimerQueue` before instantiating the `TIdSDPMultimediaSession`.

In particular, take a look at how the test case is set up, in `test\TestIdSdp.pas`:

```
procedure TestTIdSDPMultimediaSession.SetUp;
begin
  inherited SetUp;

  Self.Factory     := TMockMediaStreamFactory.Create;
  Self.Profile     := TIdAudioVisualProfile.Create;
  Self.Timer       := TIdThreadedTimerQueue.Create(false);
  Self.MS          := TIdSDPMultimediaSession.Create(Self.Profile, Self.Factory, Self.Timer);
  Self.PortBlocker := TIdMockRTPPeer.Create;

  // We only instantiate Server so that we know that GStack points to an
  // instantiated stack.
  Self.Server := TIdUdpServer.Create(nil);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo project can not be compiled. He has a lot of links to test* files. Also all the factory's was declared at the test project.

Comment: Sure. I've mentioned what needs doing, and why, in my answer. Those test files are DUnit-using test cases, as mentioned in the project's README. I have no idea what you mean in the last sentence.

Comment: I try compile CallDemo project not SIP! I think only Sip project do use DUnit for testing?

Comment: The CallDemo project has rotted: I didn't update its code in the last large set of changes I made. It will take me a long time before I have a chance to correct (or delete) CallDemo. The correct calls are all in the SIP.dpr project, in the test suite. The test suite should tell you everything about how to use the various classes.

Comment: It is a pity. The CallDemo is lighter and smaller to start with the product. But in any case, thanks for a great product...

Comment: agreed! I don't have a copy of Delphi anymore (nor even a Windows machine), so it'll be a while before I can update CallDemo. If you feel like it, by all means send me a pull request on the GitHub repository!